# Independent Autowidth in list

Tags: css

how can I make independent auto-width in list? Now if I set *width:auto* for *li* in *ul*, *li* expand to 100%. How can I reach that kind of autowidth like below?

[image: Goal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `float` and `clear` properties:

```css
li {
    background: #999;
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6gvew/1/)**